# Is this some kind of crane fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this insect inside my house in Austria and it looked like some kind of wasp-moth to me. It is quite large with about 3 cm in lenght (excluding legs).

I looked up various images of crane flies [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=crane+fly&rlz=1C1GCEU_deAT821AT821&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1_PPc7PjxAhXShP0HHci0ANYQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=1057) but couldn't find one that resembled the one I photographed, especially with those antennas and wasp-like imitation of the lower back.

Can someone help me identifying this insect and also tell me if it can bite or sting?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like something in *Ctenophora* (true crane flies), potentially [*Ctenophora ornata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenophora_ornata)? They're found in Europe and appear to have similar wing and body coloring, as well as the large antennae:

[image: Ctenophora ornata fly]

[Image from Wikimedia commons, by Jean-Marc Liotier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenophora_ornata#/media/File:Ctenophora_Ornata.jpg)

I don't believe crane flies sting, but I am not an entomologist, so I defer to the experts on that point (and the species ID as well).

Comment: No, they definately cannot sting, since they are flies (i’ve no stinger). Crane flies cannot bite either, so harmless and the coloration is only for show and mimicry.